# SharePoint Web Service - C# Class which Utilizes Two Different SharePoint Lists (two WSDLs)

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I would like to be able to work with two different SharePoint lists (using different web service calls):

For instance, right now I have two different classes that are almost identical:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;

namespace POSAutomation.Common
{
    internal class SpFunctions
    {
        private sp.canada.Lists _spService;

        public sp.canada.Lists SpService
        {
            get { return _spService ?? (_spService = new sp.canada.Lists()); }
        }

        public virtual void UpdateSpListItems(string listname, string updateXml, string user, string pw,
                                      string domain)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(updateXml))
            {
                return;
            }

            SpService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pw, domain);

            var doc = new XmlDocument();
            XmlElement batchElement = doc.CreateElement("Batch");
            batchElement.SetAttribute("OnError", "Continue");
            batchElement.SetAttribute("ListVersion", "1");
            batchElement.SetAttribute("ViewName", "");
            batchElement.InnerXml = updateXml;

            XmlNode rNode = _spService.UpdateListItems(listname, batchElement);

            XmlNamespaceManager nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(rNode.OwnerDocument.NameTable);
            nsm.AddNamespace("sp", rNode.NamespaceURI);

            XmlNodeList results = rNode.SelectNodes("//sp:ErrorCode", nsm);
            if (results != null)
                foreach (XmlNode result in results)
                {
                    string errorCode = result.InnerText;
                    if (errorCode == "0x00000000") continue;
                    ("Error Updating SharePoint List: " + errorCode).LogError();
                    ("List Name: " + listname).LogError();
                    ("Update XML: " + updateXml).LogError();
                    throw new Exception("Error Updating SharePoint List: " + errorCode);
                }
        }

        public XmlNodeList RetrieveSpItems(string listname, string query, string user, string pw,
                                           string domain)
        {
            XmlNodeList oNodes = null;
            XmlNode ndListItems = null;
            XmlNode ndQueryOptions = null;
            XmlNode ndViewFields = null;
            XmlNode ndQuery = null;
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = null;

            SpService.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pw, domain);
            xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            ndQuery = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "Query", "");
            ndViewFields = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "ViewFields", "");
            ndQueryOptions = xmlDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "QueryOptions", "");
            ndQueryOptions.InnerXml = "<IncludeAttachmentUrls>TRUE</IncludeAttachmentUrls>";
            ndViewFields.InnerXml = "";
            ndQuery.InnerXml = query;

            ndListItems = SpService.GetListItems(listname, null, ndQuery, ndViewFields, null, ndQueryOptions, null);
            oNodes = ndListItems.ChildNodes;

            return oNodes;
        }
    }
}
```

The other class contains almost exactly the same code, except for the SpService property, because it operates on a separate list (called via a separate web service):

```
private sp.pr.Lists _spService;

public sp.pr.Lists SpService
{
   get { return _spService ?? (_spService = new sp.pr.Lists()); }
}
```

Note the difference:

```
private sp.canada.Lists _spService;

public sp.canada.Lists SpService
{
   get { return _spService ?? (_spService = new sp.canada.Lists()); }
}
```

How can I simplify these two classes so that I only have one major class which contains all the code, and two smaller classes (one for each web service) that tell the major class which web service to reference?

Essentially, I'd like to create an `internal abstract SpFunctions` class which contains the code for `UpdateSPListItems()` and `RetrieveSpItems()`, and the smaller classes will only contain the `SpService` property.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If the Lists classes share an interface or are sub-classed from the same class you can use that as an injected item into a base class you'll sub-class a list-specific class from. Otherwise if they do not share a common base, but do share identical method signatures for the operations you want to call you can use the dynamic type to late-bound the calls from a base class.

Option #1:

class List
{
  protected readonly TList list;
   List(TList list)
  {
    this.list = list;
  }

void Foo()
  {
    this.list.Foo();
  }
}

class CanadaList : List
{
}

class PrList : List
{
}

Option #2

class List
{
  protected readonly dynamic list;
   List(object list)
  {
    this.list = list;
  }

void Foo()
  {
    this.list.Foo();
  }
}

class CanadaList : List
{
}

class PrList : List
{
}

Option #3

class List
{
  protected readonly objectlist;
   List(object list)
  {
    this.list = list;
  }

void Foo()
  {
    Type t = this.list.GetType();

```
t.GetMethod("Foo").Invoke(this.list, null);
```

}
}

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I think option #2 is out of the question, as the server I'm running this on only has .NET 3.5 installed and it seems `dynamic` is a 4.0 feature.  Looking into option #1 now..

Comment: If you're constrained to .NET 3.5 you can still do option #2, but it'll be much messier as you'll have to write out the code to perform the reflection. I'll edit the answer accordingly.